# Docker build is run twice after adding arg

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have Dockerfile which includes some builders, one of them is frontend where I recently added `ARG BRANCH_NAME` so I could use branch name later as a variable (I do not have .git folder in my frontend that's why I'm using this approach):

```js
FROM node:8.11 as frontend-builder
COPY frontend/package.json /frontend/package.json
COPY frontend/package-lock.json /frontend/package-lock.json
COPY ./VERSION /frontend/VERSION
WORKDIR /frontend
RUN npm install
COPY frontend/ /frontend
ARG BRANCH_NAME
RUN sed -i "s|VERSION|${BRANCH_NAME}-frontend@$(cat "VERSION")|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
RUN npm run build-prod
```

In gitlab-ci.yml I pass it like this:

```js
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" registry.xx.it
  script:
    - export TARGET=backend-builder
    - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$TARGET
    - docker pull $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME || echo "no image"
    - docker pull $IMAGE:latest || echo "no latest image"
    - docker build --target $TARGET -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

    - export TARGET=frontend-builder
    - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$TARGET
    - docker pull $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME || echo "no  image"
    - docker pull $IMAGE:latest || echo "no latest image"
    - docker build --target $TARGET -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --build-arg BRANCH_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

    - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker pull $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME || echo "no branch image"
    - docker pull $IMAGE:latest || echo "no latest image"
    - docker build -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  tags:
    - local-docker
```

after the `- export TARGET=frontend-builder` I changed line:

`- docker build --target $TARGET -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .`

to:

`- docker build --target $TARGET -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --build-arg BRANCH_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .`

so all I did was adding `--build-arg BRANCH_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`.

But now it seems to execute it all twice and once I get `$BRANCH_NAME` as it should be and other time my `$BRANCH_NAME` is empty. Does anyone have ideas why does that happen?

Comment: your `backend-builder` and `fontend-builder` image targets are same? your script has two build one without build-arg and one with it

Comment: backend-builder targets `FROM mono:6.4 as backend-builder` in dockerfile and frontend-builder targets `FROM node:8.11 as frontend-builder`

Comment: What do you mean by "it all"? You have 3 build commands in there, what exactly get executed twice?